# string conversion/parsing to return the correct values

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, json, jsonp

I have the following JSON reply where I want to parse the 4 "collation" results only:

```
jQuery191029421305245357143_1380819227858(
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 127
    },
    "command": "build",
    "spellcheck": {
        "suggestions": [
            "restaurant",
            {
                "numFound": 1,
                "startOffset": 0,
                "endOffset": 10,
                "suggestion": [
                    "restaurants"
                ]
            },
            "berl",
            {
                "numFound": 4,
                "startOffset": 11,
                "endOffset": 15,
                "suggestion": [
                    "berlin",
                    "berlin brandenburg",
                    "berlin hamburg",
                    "berliner"
                ]
            },
            "collation",
            "restaurant berlin",
            "collation",
            "restaurant (berlin brandenburg)",
            "collation",
            "restaurants berlin",
            "collation",
            "restaurant (berlin hamburg)"
        ]
    }
}
)
```

where I get the following results:

```
"restaurant"
"berl"
"restaurant berlin"
"restaurant (berlin brandenburg)"
"restaurants berlin"
"restaurant (berlin hamburg)"
```

with

```
success: function( data ) {
response( $.map(data.spellcheck.suggestions, function(item) {    
    if (typeof item != "string") return;
    if (item === "collation") return;
    return item;
}));
```

QUESTION: How can I ONLY get these 4 results:

```
"restaurant berlin"
"restaurant (berlin brandenburg)"
"restaurants berlin"
"restaurant (berlin hamburg)"
```

without the two (wrong) input results ("restaurants" + "berl")?

Thank you!

Comment: perhaps? if (item === "collation") return item;

But your JSON is invalid, it should always be {"key": "value"} and you have {"key", "key"}

Comment: @Martin: this would only return 4x "collation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access, modify the JSON to be key: value, otherwise use this solution:

```
$.map(data.spellcheck.suggestions, function (item, i) {
            if (typeof item != "string") return;
            if (item === "collation"){
                return data.spellcheck.suggestions[i+1];
            }
        })
```

Comment: I can't access the JSON. However I found out that when I do the following check: if (item === request.term) return; I solve the problem as long as there is only 1 word in the request.term. How to solve this when several words are entered in the seachbox?